# passing data via redirect laravel 5

Tags: variables, redirect, laravel, message

I have some problems when passing data via redirect  in laravel 5, i get some samples code.. here my code

**controller**

```
if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
    }else{  
        if (Hash::check($request->old_password, $employee->password)){
          $user = [                 
                'username' => $input['username'],
                'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            ];
            $employee->fill($user)->save();
            return redirect('/employees');
        }else{
            dd('test');
            $error = 'Your old password is incorrect';
            return redirect()->back()->with('error',$error);
        }

    }
```

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="old_password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password Lama</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" placeholder="Password Lama" required />{{ $errors->first('old_password') }}{{ $error = session('error') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

there is no error message, but $error cannot display my messages.. anyone can help me?

thanks a lot...

Comment: have you `print_r` the `$error` in your blade ?

Comment: no i dont use print_r, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
}else{
            dd('test');
            $error = 'Your old password is incorrect';
            return redirect()->back()->with('error',$error);
        }
```

with `dd('test')`, you are exiting the application before a value was stored in session. remove that and let redirect.

and secondly, while dealing with session, do not use `dd()`. it *may* create undesirable result as `session` is a terminable middleware.

Comment: ahh, sory.. i forget to delete that, but know my code can run.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The DD command returns info to the browser and then stops executing code. Try commented this out.